# Run grunt from post-commit git-hook

Tags: git, gruntjs, screeps

I'm trying to run the console command "grunt" in my GitHub repository folder every time  a new commit is created using GitHub Desktop (this is to link the GitHub repository's code to my Screeps account).

I've created a new file in .git/hooks "post-commit" which has the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec node -e "require('grunt').cli();"
```

How can I run Grunt automatically with every commit?

Answer (score 0):

From the command line in my environment, I ran:

```
node -e "require('grunt').cli();"
```

and it ran grunt and did the usual submission, so that part of the script is correct.

Perhaps your hook script can't find node. Is it installed globally? Do you need to activate a node environment?